# Adaptive Layout in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ios10, adaptive-layout

I am developing app using Xcode 8 (beta 1). Unfortunately, I am not able to find "Size Classes" option.

In Xcode 7, there was option "Use Size Classes".

[image]

But in Xcode 8 there is no such option. Is there any help for using Size Classes or similar in Xcode 8?

Answer (score 10):

Now you have "Use Trait Variations" which is improved version of Size Classes

[image]

You can now select device based and orientation based trait view much like size classes (iPad Pro, iPad, iPhone 6Splus, iPhone 6s, iPhone SE and iPhone 4s)

[image]

Comment: How can I have common layout for all resolutions? w - Any h - Any

Comment: Prior to Xcode 8,  any needed to be explicit, and in some places you’ll find explicit uses of any still. Often Xcode 8 hides Any from you, making it implicit instead of explicit. This resource could be useful to you:
https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/

Comment: So I have Use Auto Layout and Trait Variations checked, and my view controllers change size on IB, great. But I thought with Size Classes you could change the view in IB, do some work, then it would save those changes ONLY for that size?

Answer (score 6):

Apple introduce new feature called Trait Variations.

[image: Trait Variation]

So now you can simply create how it looks on real device.

[image]

You can simply switch devices by just clicking and also change the orientation of your view.

Comment: All iPhones in portrait at wC hR so how to make different layouts for 7+ and 4s sizes?

Comment: The new layout video is uploaded by apple you can also assign some layout objects for only some devices.

Comment: I see that video but that's when devices have different Traits. Sadly as all iPhones in portrait have same traits they cant be used to make adaptive layouts

Comment: @DhruvKhatri How can I set different Vary traits for different iPad orientation?

Comment: Check out this two videos this will guide you @TalZion  Check out Making Apps Adaptive, Part 1 from #WWDC 2016 https://developer.apple.com/wwdc16/222 Part 2 from #WWDC 2016 https://developer.apple.com/wwdc16/233