# Is there different in choose Vary for Traits all of width and height with do not enable Vary for Traits in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, landscape-portrait, size-classes

I have a doubt, if there is different with choose Vary for Traits all of width and height and do not enable Vary for Traits in interface builder.

First vc, I choose width and height in Vary for Traits:

[image]

Second vc, I do not enable the Vary for Traits:

[image]

When I run my app, or look them at `View as` module, I find the two vc is no different no matter `portrait` or `landscape` orientation.

So, I just want to know the two situation if is the same thing?

Comment: You may want to have a look here: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890055/what-is-vary-for-traits-in-xcode-8)

Comment: @Zero3nna, before I ask my question I have readed your link, this is introduce how to use size-classes in Xcode8 , my question is not mean.