# I want to set auto-layout in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, autolayout

I want to set a single button at difference place like. 
*if i select i-pad simulator then button show right side and if i select iPhone simulator left side without coding.*

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: show your work? What u have written

Comment: iPad is also an iOS device.

Comment: @ShamasS  getting some task .. l want to set a button in ios Device using Autolauout. if i select ipad simulator then that button show in right side and Top side

Comment: Sorry @Losiowaty i know ios means iphone device

Comment: We got it what you want but what you tried for your task pls mention so that we can answer accordingly.

Comment: @dahiya_boy m newbie in Auto-layout i don't know how to do this so i asked here

Comment: You have to read about auto-layout first: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: @Sagarvaishnav As a friend I suggest you First read Apple docs and learn basics otherwise you always stuck in every point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'vary for traits'
it's very powerful to use without single line of code.
see link below

[What is 'Vary for Traits' in XCode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890055/what-is-vary-for-traits-in-xcode-8)

Comment: Thanks @Dilip Bhuva