# Designing landscape oriented iPad only app in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, size-classes, adaptive-layout

How do i specify width and height of an image view specifically for iPad pro 12.9" and 10.5" and 9.7" using storyboard and how to modify leading and trailing edges for 12.9" and 10.5" as these measurements vary and are there any other ways than handle it through code?

Comment: use Vary for Traits concept, for ex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890055/what-is-vary-for-traits-in-xcode-8

Comment: you can use a multiplier for such case. Give equal width than change multiplier accordingly.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik vary for trait can be helpful if this is across different size classes (e.g: between iPhone and iPad) how could i change the size of image view in the same class (wR hR) say 12.9" pro and 10.5" pro?. Share me any working example