# swift orientation view changes

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I've search quite a bit to find information on view changes in IOS application while using swift. I've trying to do following with a orientation change for a particular view.
I've a vie with list of buttons (4) arrange like a list when device in portrait mode but I want to display them as 4 square button in a two row when device switched to landscape mode.

### For example, in portrait mode

### |         Button 1     |

---

### |         Button 2     |

---

### |         Button 3     |

---

### |         Button 4     |

In landscape mode,

---

|      Button 1   Button 2     |

|      Button 3   Button 4     |

---

I don't know if I need to build dynamic view for landscape mode to achieve this? Any ideas/help is appreciated.

Comment: use a collection view maybe? you can change the layout size on orientation change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Vary for Traits feature in the `InterfaceBuilder`.

1. Select the Vary for Traits option, the check the Width option

   [image: Vary for Traits - Width]
2. Select Landscape under Device options
3. Make desired changes, in your case rearrange buttons to the new layout
4. Click the Done Varying button

That's it. `InterfaceBuilder` has now setup the variations. Switch the orientation to see for yourself.

Comment: I'll definitely try this, just one question does it impact constraints button have in portrait mode?

Comment: With this you can set your own constraints for each trait variation. The process of doing this is a little different from normally setting up the constraints. More on that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890055/what-is-vary-for-traits-in-xcode-8

Comment: This helped. But now I'm wondering if this same technique can be used to create a specific size button for each device type/size?