# How can I add an interface variation based on a Custom Property Object?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

How can I add size class variations to my custom property objects?

[image: Size class variation symbols next to properties]

Answer (score 2):

These variations are for Traits (Size Classes / screen sizes). You cannot vary for anything else. You should do it in code.
[What is 'Vary for Traits' in XCode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890055/what-is-vary-for-traits-in-xcode-8)

Comment: thanks.. i have go through it. custom traits not possible to add in my object.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 8.3 there is option vary for Traits using that you can achieve size class behaviour.

Do one thing select device from bottom of storyboard and click on vary for traits button , then very that particular UI property after doing that click on done varying.

You will notice size class behaviour.