# How to fix button size if changing screen orientation?

Tags: ios, constraints

I have this app wherein in requires to change the screen orientation. First image is for portrait and Second image is for landscape. But there are instances that the two(2) buttons become large when I change the orientation from landscape to portrait. The third image will show you how big the  buttons after changing orientation which is it does not follow the correct portrait layout.

**portrait**

[image: This is the correct layout when in portrait orientation]

**landscape**

[image: This is the correct layout when in landscape orientation]

**bigger button when changed orientation**

[image: The bigger button when changed orientation]

The solution I tried was the image below:

**Attached equal heights**

[image: Attached to scroll view]

[image: sublayout]

**Set to 0.18 proportional height**

[image: Proportional Height]

I am having a hard time to fix this issue aside from, it is the first time I encountered this issue, the issue does not appear 100% and this issue usually appear in iPhoneX series specifically iPhoneX. Hope you can help me regarding this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using any size classes?

Comment: nope, I am just relying on the set size in constraints

Comment: try increasing the Content Hugging Priority

Comment: in which part will I increase the Content Hugging Priority?

Comment: sorry just realized you are talking about buttons Content Hugging won't help.

Comment: It's ok. Is there something you can suggest to solve the issue?

Comment: I would suggest that your use Size Classes and Vary for Traits.

Answer (score 0):

Always use size class to handle objects in different screens.
Or the other option is to use Stack.
But size class is always the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Use vary for traits (Size classes) and provide constraints for width & height for each button for different orientations.

Comment: you can refer to  this  question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890055/what-is-vary-for-traits-in-xcode-8