# Swift - UIButton is not pinning to the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I am having trouble pinning the UIButton to the bottom of my UIViewController, (There is a tab bar if that helps).
Here are the constraints of the UIButton.

[image]

Originally, it all worked fine, but ever since I added iPad support to the application I have issues. on the iPad the UIButton is pinned to the bottom of the screen, directly above the tab bar. However on iPhone, there is this empty gap at the bottom.
[image]

**What I Tried**
Doing some research I saw that sometimes split view controller causes a grey bar, I added this line of code to resolve it and it fixed the bottom bar , but this constraint issues is still causing me a headache.

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

***iPad View Hierarchy***

[image]

***iPhone View Hierarchy***

Comment: Try unchecking "Constrain to margins"

Comment: already tried that

Comment: Click on the downwards arrow next to `0` in your screenshot, make sure it's set to "View"

Comment: What does your view hierarchy look like? What are you pinning the the bottom constraint to? ScrollViews in particular can cause issues with pinning with discrepancies between iphone and iPad potentially being caused by hard coded values in other parts of the view.

Comment: @ericshieh The issue is if I pin it to the view (superview) it works on the iPhone, but on the iPad it is hidden behind the tab bar. If I pin it to the safe area, it works on iPad but there is a gap on the iPhone.

Comment: But what does the entire view hierarchy look like? It helps answered recreate your issue instead of speculating.

Comment: @EricShieh I just updated my question with the view hierarchy.

Comment: @isaacthedev you've added ipad VH, but iphone one is missing

Comment: Its hard to debug when we're given inconsistent information: The view hierarchy you sent doesn't match the problem image you've posted. FWIW, i did a quick experiment in a test app re-creating the view hierarchy you posted (A split view contained within a tab view controller) and the button pinned at the bottom in iPhone and iPad with no problem and no special adjustments required.

Comment: If possible please add demo project link

Comment: I would also encourage you to try out AutoLayout instead of Storyboards. They are better at both structuring and building your views, as well as asking for code reviews.

Comment: @isaacthedev please share the controller xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an option on Xcode to vary your constraint depending of the size of the screen.

You can create two constraints, one that works on iPad, one that works on "classic" iPhone.

[image]

Here, if I create a new constraint during the variation, I can then select on the right window which variation you want the constraint to be installed on.

There is a whole topic about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890055/what-is-vary-for-traits-in-xcode-8)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove current Constrain and Try unchecking "Constrain to margins" button.

Comment: If I do that, it works on iPhone but not on the iPad

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a constraint to a View instead of a SafeArea

Answer (score 0):

1- Give it a constant height for example 40

2- While setting constraints, uncheck (Constrain to margins)

3- Give it a proportional width constraint with the super view 0.8

Note1: If you don't want to give it a fixed height you can do the same step 3 but with height and not 0.8 but maybe 0.2 to less depending on your design.

Note2: You can use a scroll view, it will make it so easy for you