# Size class in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8

[image: View As Menu]

I can't find the size class in Xcode 8, `w:Any,h:Any`?
I already check the "use AutoLayout" and "Use Trait Variations".

Answer (score 0):

Did you found the answer? 
After I research, I found: Trait Variations in XCode 8 is improved for Size Classes.
You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631327/adaptive-layout-in-xcode-8) for more details.

Note for comment of **Dhruv Khatri**, he provides 2 link at #WWDC 2016 about Making App Adaptive, I think these will help you.